# SQL Server 2008 - For XML Path is very slow

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help to increase the performance of my query, the example is below. I have a SELECT query list multiple fields of CUSTOMER table, this is really fast, about 15 ms.  However, when I include the statement below using FOR XML PATH to grab the Customer POs (multiple) and combine them into one column, it is very slow, but it works.

Any suggestion how to increase the performance, but still getting the same results (combine the Customer POs into one column)?  A sample code would be appreciated.

```
Select 
    Col1, Col2,
    (SELECT 
        STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CustomerPO 
               FROM dbo.Tbl_CustomerPO 
               WHERE CustomerID = cus.CustomerID  
               FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')  
    ) AS CustomerPOs 
FROM Tbl_Customer cus
```

Thank you,

Comment: Could you explain what is STUFF? is it a function

Comment: I am not the expert, but I learned that stuff is removing the leading comma and spaces.. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d4bc611f-0951-4ed6-9634-c204b2304f92/stuff-and-for-xml-path?forum=transactsql

Comment: `STUFF()` is like `SUBSTRING()` and `REPLACE()` rolled into one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this ....

With a TINY recordset the "string concatenating" function method appears better from an execution plan cost, IO, and Time bases.

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'fnConcatenateCustPOs', N'fN') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.fnConcatenateCustPOs
END
GO
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnConcatenateCustPOs
    (
    @CustomerID INT
    )

    RETURNS nvarchar(max)
    --WITH ENCRYPTION

    AS 

    BEGIN
        DECLARE @StrFP nvarchar(3750)
        --DECLARE @Custpo TABLE(CustomerPOId INT, CustomerID INT)
        SET @StrFP = ''
        SET @StrFP = ''
        SELECT @StrFP =  + @StrFP + ',' + CAST(CustomerPOId AS nvarchar(50)) 
        FROM Custpo co
        WHERE co.CustomerID = @CustomerID
    RETURN SUBSTRING(@StrFP, 2, LEN(@StrFP))
    END

GO

IF OBJECT_ID(N'Cust', N'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN 
    DROP TABLE Cust
END

IF OBJECT_ID(N'Custpo', N'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN 
    DROP TABLE CustPO
END
CREATE TABLE  Cust (CustomerID INT)
CREATE TABLE CustPO  (CustomerPOId INT, CustomerId INT)

INSERT Cust
SELECT 1
UNION
SELECT 2


INSERT CustPO
SELECT 10, 1
UNION
SELECT 20, 1
UNION
SELECT 30, 2
UNION
SELECT 31, 2

SET STATISTICS IO ON 
SET STATISTICS TIME ON

SELECT CustomerId, dbo.fnConcatenateCustPOs(CustomerID)
FROM Cust cus

Select 
    CustomerID,
    (SELECT 
        STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(CustomerPOId AS nvarchar(50)) 
               FROM dbo.CustPO 
               WHERE CustomerID = cus.CustomerID  
               FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')  
    ) AS CustomerPOs 
FROM Cust cus


SET STATISTICS IO OFF
SET STATISTICS TIME OFFTry: 

Select 
    Col1, Col2,
    (
        STUFF((', ' + CustomerPO 

               FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')  
    ) AS CustomerPOs 
FROM Tbl_Customer cus
INNER JOIN dbo.Tbl_CustomerPO cpo ON cus.CustomerID = cpo.CustomerID
```

Comment: In case someone has the same problem like mine, I tried this solution and it resulted must faster.  Thank you @user3537535 for taking time putting together the sample.

Comment: Awesome solution user3537535. Using your function I managed to boost performance in 9 times. Before: CPU time = 282 ms,  elapsed time = 92 ms. After: CPU time = 16 ms,  elapsed time = 11 ms.

Comment: Beware with the join solution like that, it could doubling customer data

Comment: Same data from Tbl_Customer will be shown more than ones if it referenced more than ones in Tbl_CustomerPO

Answer (score 1):

You're introducing a `JOIN` to your query, which will inherently affect performance.
If you index the joining field `CustomerID` you can speed up this query.  Not much else to do here.

Note:  Since you're prefixing your `CustomerPo` list with a comma and a space, you should use:

```
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
```

If you don't want your resulting strings to all start with a space.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will look into this and clean up my query.